# Android Action Bar Drawers

Tags: android

I'm searching for some information about the Acion Bar Drawers described here:
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html
("Drawers: A drawer is a slide-out menu that allows users to...")

Seems like this feature is part of Android and no external library, but I can't find any information about how to implement this feature.

Comment: I know a cool open source sliding menu, is it what you are looking for? https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: Yes, i know this library, but it seems as if it is possible to do this easily without an external library with the help of these ActionBar Drawers, but I don't know how.

Comment: I doubt it. I checked the Android 4.1.1 source code and there seems no built-in sliding menu support, the handling of the "Up" event (android.R.id.home, id of the "Up" button in ActionBar) in frameworks/base has nothing to do with opening a sliding menu.

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems as if it is possible to do this easily without an external library with the help of these ActionBar Drawers,

There is no built in widget that does this. The site is simply talking about the pattern that you can use, not one that is available. The closest one to being built in is provided in the support library here (this is fairly new) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.java

Your options are :

1. Use the support library implementation used above.
2. Use a third party library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu , https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer or https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib .
3. Implement your own.